# How Can I Use Release Management To Remove \ Add Change Web.Config Tags?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, release-management, ms-release-management

As everyone knows, in VS2010 and above there is a use of `Web.config` transforms to remove add update tags and attributes in a `web.config` file .

Release management has the ability to switch values inside a `web.token.config` (convention is a variable like so : `__ConnectionString__` )

But what do I do in order to remove a whole section? Or add one for a different environment? For example, `qa` should not have a debug option, so in transforms we could Hide   Copy Code

I really am trying to connect between transforms and release management but can't, they do not behave the same , a single build definition must know which web.config file to use (i use `web.QA.config` and `web.prod.config`), while release template has only one build definition for both his `qa` and `prod` paths .

So, one release template with 2 stages (`qa->prod`) which has the same build definition cannot transform once for `qa` and once for `prod` (because again, it is defined in the build definition , from where to transform like)
Hide   Copy Code

```
:/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false /p:Configuration=QA /p:TransformConfigFiles=true
```

I have tried [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alming/archive/2015/01/19/using-web-config-transformations-and-release-manager.aspx). But it does not help the build definition transform the right `web.config` according to the release path . he just build the `web.release.config`, which does not help .

I tried many other sites as well, none of them answers the simple question: how can release management transform the web config file beyond just a simple value swap, which is not enough in my scenario, how can it add tags, remove them change deeper configurations .

Answer (score 0):

Release Management is a tool for implementing continuous delivery, ie a given build is deployed *unchanged* (save for configuration values) through the different stages of the delivery pipeline until it fails a stage (at which point it is deemed void and progresses no further) or reaches the end of the pipeline.

If you need to change anything but configuration values between stages it is probably a symptom of your environments being fundamentally different between stages which is against one of the core tenets of continuous delivery. Or it may be you are trying to deploy different builds to different stages which is definitely *not* continuous delivery.

My blog post series [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs/) explains how to use Release Management for continuous delivery. [This](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-preparing-deployment-pipeline/) post explains one of several ways to manage web.config - please note that there is no concept of web.$some_environment$.config.

Having said all that most of us have to live with dysfunctions so if you really do need to have changing web.configs then using functionality such as xdt:Transform="Remove" should work.

As a footnote to all this you should be aware that there is a completely new - web-based - version of Release Management coming out with TFS 2015 Update 1 and it may pay to wait for this version if you can, although might be late this year or early next year before it ships. Check out [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3736) video for a taster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the reason for the change between environment is because in qa \ prod you do not want debug mode\ yellow screen \ tracing that only happens in QA environment .

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reply , the reason for the change between environment is because in qa \ prod you do not want debug mode\ yellow screen \ tracing that only happens in QA environment .

i wondered why it was so hard to get all of these web config files (of different environments) transformed .
then i looked at the build server output , and found it all !
at the build folder that was created in your build machine , you would find all of the transformed files for each version
\build server ip\c$\Builds\some number\solution Name\Build Definition name\Sources\TFS
->web.config.QA
->web.config.Prod
fully transformed .
you can then x copy it to your destination and then rename it (could be done with powershell) or use release management to do it .